# I can not retrieve information on a web page

Tags: vba, extract

the principle: load a page and recover the information contained in the tag a

here is the source code:

```
    <div class="w3-row w3-white w3-padding w3-hide-medium w3-hide-small" style="margin-top:5px;">

        <div class="w3-col s5 notranslate" style="margin:4px 0 6px 0">
            <a class="w3schools-logo" href="//www.w3schools.com">w3schools</a>
        </div>
  </div>
```

but at the execution of my code, I see this error : property or method not supported by this object

```
Private Function CreerNavigateur()
Dim IE As Object
Dim oDoc As Object
Dim Htable, maTable, hyper As Object
Dim text As String

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = True
IE.navigate "www.w3schools.com"
WaitIE IE
    ' Page chargée, on continue
   Set oDoc = IE.Document
   Set Htable = oDoc.getElementsByTagName("div")(1)
   Set maTable = Htable.getElementsByTagName("a")
   MsgBox maTable
   Set hyper = maTable.getElementsByClassName("w3schools-logo")
   text = hyper.innerText
   MsgBox text
 IE.Quit
    'On libère les variables
    Set IE = Nothing
    Set IEDoc = Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are receiving is because `Htable.getElementsByTagName` returns a collection of elements, and that collection doesn't have the method `maTable.getElementsByClassName`. You need to reference the first item in the collection (using `maTable(0)`), then you can access the `href` and `innertext` as follows:

```
Private Function CreerNavigateur()
Dim IE As Object
Dim oDoc As Object
Dim Htable, maTable, hyper As Object
Dim text As String

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = True
IE.navigate "www.w3schools.com"
WaitIE IE
    ' Page chargée, on continue
    Set oDoc = IE.Document
    Set Htable = oDoc.getElementsByTagName("div")(1)
    MsgBox Htable.innerhtml
    Set maTable = Htable.getElementsByTagName("a")
    MsgBox maTable(0).href
    MsgBox maTable(0).innertext
 IE.Quit
    'On libère les variables
    Set IE = Nothing
    Set IEDoc = Nothing
End Function
```